# SPI frequency for slave and master?

Tags: stm32, spi, frequency, register

I have been trying to hook up [ADE7758](https://www.analog.com/media/cn/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADE7758.pdf) with STM32F401, but I am having a problem understanding the frequency part of it.
There is no minimum or maximum frequency for SPI CLK in the datasheet, and my SPI on the STM32 is set at 84 MHz.
It only states the SCLK which is a range of frequency for the external oscillator that we need to attach with the circuit.

Do both master and slave need to have the same frequency? or should one be more than or less than the other?

I have searched the internet before posting a question here.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question whether "master and slave need to have the same frequency": Do you understand to which signal in SPI "frequency" refers?

Comment: Also, the datasheet pretty clearly states a maximum frequency for SCLK in Table 2.

Comment: SCLK is the frequency to attach an external crystal which should be between 5 and 15 Mhz, but the frequency on which SPI needs to communicate is not clear. I am new at SPI protocol.

Comment: @davidweb no, that would be CLKIN.

Comment: CLKIN : Master Clock for ADCs and Digital Signal Processing. An external clock can be provided at this logic input.
Alternatively, a parallel resonant AT crystal can be connected across CLKIN and CLKOUT to provide a clock
source for the ADE7758. The clock frequency for specified operation is 10 MHz. Ceramic load capacitors of a few tens of picofarad should be used with the gate oscillator circuit. Refer to the crystal manufacturer’s datasheet for the load capacitance requirements

Comment: SCLK: Serial Clock Input for the Synchronous Serial Interface. All serial data transfers are synchronized to this clock (see the Serial Interface section). The SCLK has a Schmidt-trigger input for use with a clock source that has a slow edge transition time, for example, optoisolator outputs.

Comment: exactly, @davidweb! You found the difference: SCLK is **not** the external reference oscillator input; hobbs is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From **Table 1 - Specifications**, the maximum, minimum, and typical SPI frequencies are given. I say *typical*, as that's what they have used for characterisation in the datasheet so it will be guaranteed to work as specified under those conditions (not accounting for external factors, such as interference etc).

[image]

The ADE7758 does not generate an internal SPI clock, so it is solely dependent on the STM generated clock. If you are generating a nominal 10 MHz clock, that happens to be 10.25 MHz if you don't have fractional clock dividers, it will be absolutely fine. Generally speaking, aim for the typical value then stick well within the absolutes.

Answer (score 3):

SPI Master will drive the SPI Slave clock line, there is no way of having those frequencies different.

But since the slave has its own limits, the master should not go faster than the slave is capable of supporting.

The maximum frequency for ADC SPI interface (SCLK) is shown in Table 2. See the allowed high and low pulse minimum widths. Both are 50 ns, that makes the minimum supported period of 100 ns, which is 10 MHz. You should not go faster than 10 MHz on SPI interface. And it's irrelevant of CLKIN frequency being used for ADC sampling and processing.

Comment: So what is the margin for that? I have used 8 Prescaler and it is becoming 10.5Mhz and if I use 16 it will become 5.25Mhz.
a margin of 0.5Mhz is fine or not?

Comment: The exact spi speed is not that important, provided it satisfies your general needs. The adc might work ok at slightly higher speed, this happens very often with display controllers using spi bus. But the stability is not guaranteed, and you can have one device working, while some other device will fail, communicating garbage.

Comment: @david 10.5 < 15, so why not?

Comment: @MituRaj Because CLKIN is not the SCLK. ADC sampling/processing clock is not the same as SPI interface clock.

Comment: @davidweb no margin (per the specs). Actually ideally you should be *lower* than 10 MHz; since both phases must be >= 50ns, a 10MHz clock leaves zero tolerance for duty cycle or jitter, while something like an 8MHz clock leaves you some wiggle room.

Answer (score 0):

On SPI, the clock is provided from the master to the slave, thus the slave does not have a "frequency" set, since the master provide the clock speed through the SCL(SCK) Line.

The slave will have a frequency range to which it will work, the master has to provide a clock within this range.

You can even change the frequency during communication.

You are confused with serial bus, where a baudrate is defined and both devices has to communicate at a specific speed.

Comment: I am not confused with serial bus, I have used LIS3DSH and it has its SPI frequency mentioned in its datasheet. I know that the master sets the frequency for slaves but the slave also has a limit that we cannot exceed.